# How to make a loop run x frames per second?

Tags: c++, winapi

So, I got this code, which roughly goes like this:

```
while (!exit) {
    // typing some stuff
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = GetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole);
    pos.Y -= rows + 3; // return to first pos to rewrite
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
}
```

but at this moment it depends on how fast my computer is running on how often this loop is triggered. How can I limit the times per second or frames per second that this loop is triggered to like, let's say 60 fps?

Comment: [Fix your timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to the language, and I was sent to the post multiple times while searching through the internet, but after reading I don't get how I can use it in my own code. I would be expecting to be setting some time frame and then waiting for that time frame, and not pass the delta time into an unknown function (to me)?

Comment: The article is language-agnostic, what unknown function? I mean you can just put `sleep` at the end of the loop if that's good enough for you.

Comment: I tried, but it seemed not precise enough for higher fps.

Comment: Basically you have an accumulator for the amount of time that has passed that you continually add to. When it reaches the desired time between frames you set the accumulator to 0, draw the frame, and repeat the process. Once you have it working with a simple spin loop you might want to experiment with `Sleep` but you'll want to research `timeBeginPeriod` and experiment a bit to get the resolution you need. `Sleep` will never be 100% reliable but it'll probably be close enough.

Comment: you can use `high_resolution_clock`. the period is a nanosecond, or ratio<1, 1000000000> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/high-resolution-clock-struct?view=msvc-170 and here is a sample  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/steady-clock-struct?view=msvc-170#example

Comment: It's been a few days, has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so if you wanted your program to run at 60 fps, that would mean that one frame should take 1/60 s to run, right? 1/60 s = 16.666 ms, which is approximately 17 ms. Here's what you could do.

```
while (!exit) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // typing some stuff
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = GetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole);
    pos.Y -= rows + 3; // return to first pos to rewrite
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // limit fps
    while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() < 17) {
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
}
```